# Do the sentences make sense in the following situation?

Tags: conditionals

Here is a situation: I don't know if he ate the cake. I think in my head:

1. If he didn't eat the cake, I'll have it.
2. If he hasn't eaten the cake, I'll have it.

Do the above sentences make sense?

Comment: Imagine a user reading the title on the home page. What exactly is the problem? Is it grammatical, is it about meaning, collocation, slang? You've identified the grammar notion, why not use the same in the title?

Comment: This is your fourth question *in a row* asking if one or more sentences make sense. Who's going to upvote a question with vague titles like that? C'mon! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably apply subjective mood, as you're imagining a situation. Thus your sentence should be:

> If he didn't eat the cake, I **would** have it.

Note when you hypothesize a present situation, you should use "would/could..." in the independent clause and past tense or "were" in the dependent clause.

Answer (score 1):

(2) would be the most natural (if I arrive and find the cake gone). (1) would only apply if there was a particular time at which I think he may have eaten it.

> If he didn't eat the cake with his lunch, I'll have it for tea.